# Unable to start react project after npm start?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a react project using npx create-react-app. But when I cd into the project folder and run "npm start", it just does not work. I have tried all the possible solutions I could no the internet without any success. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[Screenshot of  the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEvNE.png)

Comment: try first `npm i` and then `npm start`

Comment: Have you tried to do the steps listed in the error?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on the error screen? Have you tried installing the missing dependency manually?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the steps listed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to start a project from within `/Users/vinaykangralkar/Desktop/roboter`, however, it looks like you've already also installed some npm packages in `/Users/vinaykangralkar` which is a parent of that folder.

Create-react-app is complaining that you have nested these projects. You can likely fix the error by deleting the following files from `/Users/vinaykangralkar` if you no longer need them:

```
package.json
package-lock.json
node_modules/ (This one is a directory)
```

Or you can fix it by moving `roboter` to somewhere outside of `/Users/vinaykangralkar`

Comment: Great :) Please consider [accepting my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your issue